# jQuery remove doesn't work correctly, jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML5 code (for example):

```
  <form id="peopleFormView">
     <input type="checkbox" name="name1" value="5" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="name3" value="2" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="name4" value="3" />
  </form>

  <table id="domain5">
     <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

this code is handled with JS:

```
 $(function(){
   registerPerformersClickHandler();
 });

 function registerPerformersClickHandler(){

   $('#peopleFormView input').click(function(){
     var IdPerson = $(this).val();

     if ($('#performer'+IdPerson).length == 0){
         performer.add(IdPerson);
     }
     else{
         performer.del(IdPerson);
     }

 });

 var performer = {
     del: function(IdPerson){
       $('#performer'+IdPerson).remove();
    }
 }
```

Recognition that element exists $('#performer'+IdPerson).length == 0  work fine, but when the element is added

```
  <tr id="performer5">
    <td>Surname name</td>
  </tr>
```

and I click again to the same input, JS correctly calls performer.del(), but nothing happen, no error, no reaction. If I call remove twice like this:

```
var performer = {

 add: function(IdPerson){
    var requestData = {
        className : 'Performer',
        method : 'getPerformerRowView',
        params : IdPerson
    };

    $.post(openAjaxLoader, requestData)
       .success(function(data){
          orchestraDomain.addPerformerToDomain(data.IdDomain, data.performer);
       })
       .error(function(data){
          window.alert(data.error);
       })
 }
 ,
 del: function(IdPerson){
    alert( $('[id=performer'+IdPerson+']').length ); 
    $('#performer'+IdPerson).remove();
    $('#performer'+IdPerson).remove();
 }

}

var orchestraDomain = {

 addPerformerToDomain: function(IdDomain, performer){
     $('#domain'+IdDomain+' tbody').append(performer);
 }

}
```

.. it works. If the call is in this way

```
 var performer = {
     del: function(IdPerson){
       $('#performer'+IdPerson).remove().remove();
    }
 }
```

.. it doesnt work. I dont see a problem, seeing someone of you?

:: Is there any kind of magic, don't you think?

Comment: In one place you are using a `-`, and not in the other. `if ($('#performer'+IdPerson).length == 0){` vs `$('#performer-'+IdPerson).remove();`

Comment: It sounds like you have duplicate Id's, which would explain why `.remove().remove()` doesn't work but `$(sel).remove();$(sel).remove();` works.

Comment: `remove()` must be `void`, this means that it returns nothing, nothing is not an object that has method `remove()`.

Comment: Any chance you could produce a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I checked it in FireBug and with Chrome and the ID created by '#performer'+IdPerson is truly unique.

Comment: You don't have two `tbody` elements do you? From what you've posted, that'd be the only way it could be getting in there twice.

Answer (score 2):

You have duplicate ID's, and this is why I think that and how to confirm:

Removing an element by ID should only need to be done once. If you have to do it twice, you have two elements with that id.

`.remove().remove()` doesn't work because the first .remove will remove all selected elements. It only removes selected elements, which should be only one element.

The fact that selecting the element twice and removing it twice gets the desired result also confirms that you have two elements with that id. Below is one more test you can run:

```
var performer = {
    del: function(IdPerson){
        alert( $('[id=performer'+IdPerson+']').length ); // if > 1, your html is invalid and you have duplicate id's.
        $('#performer'+IdPerson).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: The test alert( $('[id=performer'+IdPerson+']').length ). It returns 2. I saved the HTML (copy from FireBug), tried to find duplicate, but there is no other.. problem can be caused with this: <input type="datetime" name="finishAt" placeholder="end of event" value="" pattern="^((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\.((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\.([0-9]{4}) ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$" required />

Comment: Post your `add` method and more than likely that will show why it is happening.